# Ubuntu Tweak don't work

Tags: apt, updates, 15.04, ppa, repository

How can I make work Ubuntu Tweak in Ubuntu 15.04? If I try to install him with simple commands like that don't work

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

It give me a error :

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

So, know anyone any way to make it work in Ubuntu 15.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means there is no package version for `vivid`. You can try download this package manually from this repository page and install that. But it doesn't mean it really not available for `vivid`, usually maintainer just didn't build this package in `vivid` environment, but it still could work in newer Ubuntu release.

[image: All available Ubuntu versions]

Comment: k... and do you know how I can install manually that packaged I need it?

Comment: Google this ppa name, load ppa website and download package, install this from cli or using gdebi, see more in Ubuntu wiki about manual installing of packages, I'm sorry but not at the desktop right now